# angular-bootstrap modal on nested view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap modal directive from here: [DOCUMENTATION](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#modal) but for some reason I cannot make it work.

When I click on the button which calls the function, it shows a line over the darker background as you can see [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/X5C3agUm1daNi/giphy.gif). However you can see the template loaded in the developer tools, [check the gif](http://makeagif.com/i/YyUuwO).

You can check my [gist with the files](https://gist.github.com/ezequieltejada/18fb4fdfd09767c41372cdd5297bf80b).

Any sugestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this two divs:

YOUR CODE

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login / Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Login Form</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CHANGE TO THIS

```
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login / Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Login Form</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the `<div class="modal fade">` is who dont let see the rest of the content.